# Fetch, store and use JSON variable with express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I've been struggling trying to understand how to access and and process data using HTTP method routes (get, put, post...). So far, I've been able to fetch the JSON data and store it in a global variable.

```
var pokedata;

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json')
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
        pokedata = json;
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("It was not possible to fetch the data.")
});
```

I wanted to send responses HTTP GETs to `http://localhost:3000/pokemon/XXX/` with some data about that Pokémon number XXX (which is in the JSON called pokedata). However, any attempt at looping through the data inside GET, triggers the error:

```
    app.get('/pokemon/:pokemonid', function (req, res) {
        //not the desired behaviour but a sample of what doesn't work.
        for (let {name: n, weight: w, height: h} of pokedata) {
            res.send(n, w, h); 
        }
    });

    TypeError: pokedata[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
```

Can't seem to find anything related in the express docs. Any help is well received.

Comment: what is the structure of pokedata? From the error you're getting it seems that it's an object, not an array. `for .. of` loops don't work on objects, just iterables (with arrays being the most familiar iterable)

Comment: When do you call ```fetch```? If you ```console.log``` the ```pokedata``` in the ```app.get```, what does it look like?

Comment: @Wainage like this:

`{ pokemon: 
   [ { id: 1,
       num: '001',
       name: 'Bulbasaur',
       img: 'http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png',
       type: [Object],
       height: '0.71 m',
       weight: '6.9 kg',
       candy: 'Bulbasaur Candy',
       candy_count: 25,
       egg: '2 km',
       spawn_chance: 0.69,
       avg_spawns: 69,
       spawn_time: '20:00',
       multipliers: [Object],
       weaknesses: [Object],
       next_evolution: [Object] },
     { id: 2,
       num: '002',
       name: 'Ivysaur', ... ]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pokedata` is an object, and you don't want to iterate on it. Instead you want to iterate on `pokedata.pokemon`, which is an array of the pokemon. So a small modification to your code is all that's needed:

```
for (let {name: n, weight: w, height: h} of pokedata.pokemon) {
    res.send(n, w, h); 
}
```

Comment: Smart answer to a not that smart question. Thank you. Just wanted to point out that it was supposed to be `console.log(n, w, h);` not `res.send(n, w, h);` so that people don't get confused.